Item Not Visible While Dragging
I am using React DND-Kit to allow drag and drop on a screen that I am developing. I initially used the "Sortable" example (https://docs.dndkit.com/presets/sortable) and have began modifying this to meet my needs, however it appears to be failing slightly.
I had the line useSortable({id: customer.id}) initially, which created the animations when you drag and drop, but when you drop the item it reset to it's position.
Changing this to useSortable({id: customer}) now updates the list when you drop the item, but you cannot see the item when you are dragging it.
Why is the item not showing when you drag it?
Full code:
SortableCustomerRecord:
import React from 'react';
import {useSortable} from '@dnd-kit/sortable';
import {CSS} from '@dnd-kit/utilities';

export function SortableDriverRecord({ customer }) {
const {
attributes,
listeners,
setNodeRef,
transform,
transition,
} = useSortable({id: customer});

const style = {
transform: CSS.Transform.toString(transform),
transition,
};



return (
  <div ref={setNodeRef} style={style} {...attributes} {...listeners}>
    <p>{customer.name}</p>
  </div>
);
}

RoundCustomerList:
    import axios from "axios";
    //React
import React, { useRef, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
//Icons
import { faTrash } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
//Gloabal auth via user
import { useAuthContext } from "../../../Hooks/useAuthContext";
//Components
import Spinner from "../../../Components/Loading/Spinner";
import {SortableCustomerRecord} from "./SortableCustomerRecord";
import {
  DndContext, 
  closestCenter,
  KeyboardSensor,
  PointerSensor,
  useSensor,
  useSensors,
} from '@dnd-kit/core';
import {
  arrayMove,
  SortableContext,
  sortableKeyboardCoordinates,
  verticalListSortingStrategy,
} from '@dnd-kit/sortable';

export default function RoundCustomerList({
  selectedRound,
  roundCustomers,
  setRoundCustomers,
  setSelectedCustomer,
  customersLoading,
}) {
console.log(roundCustomers)

  
  const [items, setItems] = useState(roundCustomers);
  const { user } = useAuthContext();

  const sensors = useSensors(
    useSensor(PointerSensor),
    useSensor(KeyboardSensor, {
      coordinateGetter: sortableKeyboardCoordinates,
    })
  );
  
  function handleDragEnd(event) {
    const {active, over} = event;
    
    if (active.id !== over.id) {
      setItems((items) => {
        const oldIndex = items.indexOf(active.id);
        const newIndex = items.indexOf(over.id);

        return arrayMove(items, oldIndex, newIndex);
      });
    }
  }
  
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("list changed")

    const data = {
      roundCustomers: [],
    };

    items.forEach(function(customer, index){ 
      data.roundCustomers.push({
        customerId: customer.customerId,
        roundId: selectedRound,
        position: index,
      });
    });

    axios
      .post(
        `https://${import.meta.env.VITE_SERVER_URL}/api/round/${selectedRound}/customers/`,
        data,
        {
          headers: { Authorization: `bearer ${user.token}` },
        }
      )
      
      

  }, [items]);
  

  

  return (
   <div className="mb-3" style={{ height: "100%" }}>
    <DndContext 
      sensors={sensors}
      collisionDetection={closestCenter}
      onDragEnd={handleDragEnd}
    >
      <SortableContext 
        items={items}
        strategy={verticalListSortingStrategy}
      >
        {items.map(customer => <SortableCustomerRecord key={customer.id} customer={customer} />)}
      </SortableContext>
    </DndContext>
   </div>


You can't put customer as id in useSortable({ id: customer }):
Type '{ id: number; name: string; }' is not assignable to type 'UniqueIdentifier'. ts(2322).
Use customer.id instead: useSortable({ id: customer.id }).
